# How to count all possible path in a 2d grid?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve a problem where a source grid coordinate and an end grid coordinate is given. I have to count all possible paths from source grid to end grid. what algorithm should I use?

Comment: This question needs some more details (like can you go diagonal or just up/down/left/right, are there obstacles, etc.) and preferably some code.

Comment: I can only go down and right. I am new to competitive programming. I am just trying to find an idea how to solve this.

Comment: Is that [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55902034/555045)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform `N + M` steps, `N` of them are steps down, and `M` of them are steps right.

There are `C(N+M, N)` variants to make this path, where `C()` is [number of combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition)

Comment: that means (N+M)cN?

Comment: There is a lot of different [notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#History_and_notation) for the same term `number of combinations` or `binomial coefficient`, `(N+M)cN` means the same

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your end-coordinate is m steps down and n steps right from your source-coordinate, isn't it the number of possible path (m+n)Cn? If you want to draw the paths using a modern programming language, then it is a different story.